# Azure DevOps: PR build validation with resource-triggered pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have four repos and four pipelines:

- pipelineA in repoA
- pipelineB in repoB
- pipelineC in repoC
- pipelineD in repoD

pipelineD depends on the other pipelines through *pipeline resource* definitions. So when any of pipeline[A-C] succeed, pipelineD will be triggered using the corresponding artifacts.

In particular, if I create a PR to main in repoA, pipelineA will be automatically triggered (due to *Build Validation Policy*). And when pipelineA completes, pipelineD will be triggered, using the correct versions of the resources (i.e. the PR build for repoA, and latest builds on main branch for repoB and repoC).
This already works.

But: I want to block merging of the PR in repoA if pipelineD fails. **Does anyone know how to achieve that?**

I've tried adding pipelineD as a *build validation policy* in repoA, but then pipelineD will be run using the latest artifacts from the main branch of repoA.

All pipelines are YAML pipelines. All repos are in the same DevOps project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.